# What airport is this?

Tags: airport-identification

A friend of mine asked for some help identifying the airport in the picture below. He needs it for a geocache.

Google reverse image search was, perhaps unsurprisingly, not very helpful. We've spent some time on Google maps, but there are many airports :-). Other than that, I'm really out of ideas.

We have some reason to believe that it is located in Europe, presumably excluding Turkey and Russia.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the GC code for the geocache? That might give more clues.

Comment: @CatchAsCatchCan It's a German geocache and it doesn't have a GC code AFAIK, will check, though. Anyway, we've found it, will post an answer :-).

Comment: Besides the simple fact that his is an airport, what does the question have to do with aviation?

Comment: @MichaelHall I wasn't sure if it was going to be on topic, but the existence of the airport-identification tag settled it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brute forcing Google maps finally paid off. It's Bordeaux airport:

[image]

Comment: Wow, nice finding. I thought it might be in France because there are many roundabouts in the vicinity but that was merely a guess.